# Git: How to work on two files using using different synchronized branches?

Tags: git

Notice: This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032221/how-to-work-on-two-independent-things-simultaneously-using-git-branches), so also no duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review). Also not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516719/work-on-two-git-branches-simultaneously-on-local-env)

#### Abstract:

I'd like to edit two files within the same *branch*(?) (both open in same IDE; both compiling to the same executable), while being able to commit/push/pull them on individual branches.

#### Concrete Example

**Scenario steps:**

- I'm creating a `Computer` component in file `computer.file`. I manage it in branch `component/computer`.
- I figure out, I will need to implement a `Mouse` component in file `mouse.file`. I also manage it in branch `component/computer`
- I will be working on `Computer` and `Mouse` simultaneously (adjusting `Mouse` to what `Computer` needs).
- I'm doing regular local commits to save my progress.
- While I'm still working on both components, other team members like to also use the `Mouse` component in it's current version.
- The `Mouse` component should best be shared in the main branch (`develop` branch). But as the `Computer component` is long before finished, `develop` branch should not know about it.

**Problem:**

`Computer.file` and `Mouse.file` are worked on within the same branch (`component/computer`), so merging that with `develop`, will also add `Computer.file` into `develop` (which is unwanted)

**What I want:**

I'd like to be able push/merge only `Mouse.file` into develop (regularly). 
My idea of the solution is to have `Computer.file` on branch `component/computer` and `Mouse.file` on branch `component/mouse`, while being able to edit both branches in one IDE and branch and being able to commit/push/merge both branches independently.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution of editing each file on its own branch is correct. Conceptually you have two different features that are being worked simultaneously, but imagine they are being worked by two different people as well. Someone else is working on Mouse while you work on Computer and Computer *depends* on Mouse. In that case you would have to coordinate closely and regularly bring the changes from Mouse (or `develop` if you're willing to wait until they land there) into your branch, either with `rebase` or `merge`.

The fact that you happen to be developing both of these features together, means that you get to decide how to "coordinate closely" with yourself. You *could* maintain two branches and only put changes to the proper feature on each branch, and then keep rebasing `component/computer` onto `component/mouse` every time you make a change to `component/mouse` that `component/computer` needs. I would probably find that a little cumbersome though. In the past when I've done something similar I would work on a single branch (let's call it `component/computer`) and then do one of these:

1. Simply make sure you never put changes to both features in the same commit. Later, when you're ready to Pull Request one set of those commits into `develop` you would create the `component/mouse` branch and cherry-pick the set of commits you want from `component/computer`. Afterwards, drop those commits from `component/computer`. (Note you can use interactive rebase to quickly do both of those actions.) This way you don't have to keep switching branches back and forth all day long and continuously rebasing `component/computer` onto `component/mouse` (or merging, etc).
2. If you're willing to squash your commits later **and** the changes are always separated by files, you could skip #1 and just commit all your changes as you go whenever you feel like it. When you're ready to PR something into `develop`, `git reset` your branch back to where you started, and then only stage and commit the files you wish to PR into `develop`. Create a branch at that single commit called `component/mouse` and push it. Then stage the remaining files and create a second commit and call this `component/computer`.

Repeat either 1 or 2 for each PR you wish to make with Mouse changes into `develop`, starting with where you left off on `component/computer`.